# No module named flask_mongoengine

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, importerror, mongoengine

I'm having a problem importing flask-mongoengine. The error I'm getting is:

```
ImportError: No module named flask_mongoengine
```

I am using a virtual environment (installed using sudo), with the following requirements.txt:

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Login==0.4.0
flask-mongoengine==0.9.3
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
mongoengine==0.13.0
pymongo==3.4.0
requests==2.2.1
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.1
```

I installed these using:

```
sudo -H pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Everything else seems to be imported and working fine, but flask-mongoengine is giving me issues. I've searched for answers, uninstalled and reinstalled many times, but cannot find the problem. I feel like it may be a problem with my PYTHONPATH? Or with virtualenv? But for now I am at a loss.

Essentially: pip recognizes that it's installed, but I can't import it in my app.py.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. If you need more info, I will provide to the best of my ability.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to install .whl file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask-mongoengine?

Comment: I just tried installing via the .whl file, but there was no change. When I tried, pip told me that the package and dependencies were already installed

Comment: Do you have several pythons on your PC like several versions of it?

Comment: I also have python3.5 installed. Do you think that this might be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes it can be, seems like your pip told you about your Python 3.5. Write in your command line this: pip2.7 install flask-mongoengine, and check if it works for you

Comment: Unfortunately installing with pip2.7 didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try installing

```
pip install flask-mongoengine
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it installing it individually this way, but it has not worked

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `sudo` in virtual environments. Just

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

after activating the virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need update something, try `pip install -U -r requirements.txt`